# ng-class condition working only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-class

I have a weird issue I don't understand with a class toggle condition I'm trying to set up.

I have a page with one modal I want to show if a user press a specific button.
When pressed, It changes a variable `moodActive` to `true` and when this bool is set to true the modal gets displayed:

```
<div ng-include src="'partials/phrase.html'" class="all_height nav_wrapper" navimation></div>

  <div ng-include src="'partials/mood-select.html'" class="select_mood all_height" ng-class="moodActive ? 'active' : 'hidden'"></div>
```

inside the `partials/mood-select.html` template I have a close button with the following ng-click:

```
<b class="close icon-close" ng-click="moodActive = false"></b>
```

loading the page work, clicking on the button shows the modal, and using the close button hides it properly. the problem is that clicking on the button again has not effect anymore. it sets the bool to true again but the ng-class condition doesn't get triggered.

Am I missing something? Everything is within the same controller.

**UPDATE: ADDED CONTROLLER**

I've stripped parts of the controller that are not relevant to the case.

```
app.controller('selectionController', function($scope, $location, $http, Utils, Actions, Moods, Places) {

  //USER NAV
  $scope.moodActive = false;
  $scope.actionActive = false;

  $scope.resultats = function(){
    var mood;
    var actions;

    //Checking for mood variable
    if(mood == null){
      // mood isn't defined
      $scope.moodActive = true;
    }

  }
```

**MARKUP**

```
<a href='' class='btn red_to_blue' data-js='step_submit_phrase' ng-click="resultats()">Définir mon mood</a>
```

Comment: Please show your controller code.

Comment: It looks like some conflicts between parent/child scopes.

Comment: Van you show the controller... Also is a good practice get rid of those ugly ng-include and make your own directive/component with own logic and scope to manage those things

Comment: I've updated my question with asked information

Comment: When you close the modal, you are most likely setting a hide style on the modal itself. The class you are setting to active is most likely making the include itself visible but not actually opening the modal. Please show your modal code if you want some more advice on that.